# How do I convert a base type into a type that inherits it?

Tags: arrays, go, casting, slice

Suppose I have

```golang
type Tags []string
```

I have code that produces a `[]string`:

```
b := []string{"hello", "world"}
```

How do I get `b` so it is type `Tags` and not `[]string`?

Comment: `t := Tags(b)`. This is called a _type_ _conversion_. Note that []string is not a "base type" and Tags doesn't  "inherit" anything (Tags is a named type, its underlying type is []string). Please take the Tour of Go for all these language fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
b := Tags([]string{"hello", "world"})
fmt.Printf("%T\n", b)
```

Which outputs:

```
main.Tags
```

But you can also use `Tags` in the [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) as the type directly:

```
b2 := Tags{"hello", "world"}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", b2)
```

Which again outputs:

```
main.Tags
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/14K8i29SudK).